# How to run some batch script on all MWAA Airflow worker nodes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

Is there a way to run a specific batch script on every worker node that MWAA spins up?

Is there any feature in airflow that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the latest version, you can run the scripts as a startup scripts on every worker. For this the scripts needs to be available in the S3 bucket and its absolute path is provided to MWAA environment "Startup script file "
For more details - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/using-startup-script.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no practical way to do this because it is not supported by MWAA. Set up of the individual nodes is *managed* by AWS, which means you don't get to mess with it.